# How to show and hide menu based on start and scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two menus on a page, I am trying to show the one when the page is loaded and the other when there is a scroll.
This is my page [Link](http://dev.thegabrielmethod.com/gabriel/)

I would like to show the white part when position is at the top
and the blue part when there is a scroll past the top position

This is what am trying presently

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('header').removeClass('nav-bar-below op-page-header cf').addClass('banner include-nav');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('header').removeClass('banner include-nav').addClass('nav-bar-below op-page-header cf');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
});//]]> 

</script>
```

can some one please help its not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just detect if the scroll is at the top of the page or not whenever scroll event fired. if yes, show white header, and vice versa

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollPosition === 0) {
        //show white header
    }
    else {
        //show blue header
    }
}
```

Of course you have to make sure when page first load, it show the white one first (use css). since the code above won't run Until user do scroll (fire this event)

***EDIT**

for this :
"and the blue part when there is a scroll past the top position"

you can try this plugin
http://stickyjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

sample code for fix the menu at top position.

```
$(document).scroll(function() {

var y = $(document).scrollTop()
var header = $('.include-nav');
var blue-menu = $('.cf');
var screenHeight = header.height();
if (y >= screenHeight) {
    blue-menu.css({
        position : "fixed",
        "top" : "0",
        "left" : "0"
    });
    header.css("position", "relative");
} else {
    blue-menu.css("position", "relative");
}
});
```